# How make standard login not related to web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my project I implement login.
Page login.aspx page contains:

```
<asp:Login ID="MainLogin" runat="server" onloggingin="MainLogin_LoggingIn"></asp:Login>
```

on server side this page:

```
protected void MainLogin_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(MainLogin.UserName, MainLogin.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(MainLogin.UserName, MainLogin.RememberMeSet);
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(MainLogin.UserName, MainLogin.Password))
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.GetConnectionString());
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE login=@login and pass=@pass", myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", MainLogin.UserName);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", MainLogin.Password);
            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader Reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                Session["curUserRole"] = Reader["role"].ToString();
                Session["curUserLogin"] = MainLogin.UserName;
                Server.Transfer(Request.Url.LocalPath);
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(MainLogin.UserName, MainLogin.RememberMeSet);
                return;
            }
            //Reader.Close();
            //myCommand.Connection.Close();
            //myConnection.Close();                    
        }
        else { 

        }        
    }
```

variable that I needed later I write into session variables.
On web.config I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="Admin" password="sa" />

        </credentials>        
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

So I typed login - "Admin" and pass - "sa", then it checks into the web.config, if find item user it checks this item in database, I need check item only in database and if there one load startup page, else load again Login.aspx.

Comment: not really sure what you trying to do but that's not really a good way of checking user name login have you looked at Encrypting the config section and or storing the user name pass word encrypted in a DB and not in Clear Text..? from what you have you are trying to do basic forms authentication is this correct Also how come you are not checking to see if you have any values returned from the DB Query before assigning values to the session objects this is what we all negative assumptions

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.  You should use the built-in SqlMembershipProvider.

Comment: now it in clear text, encrypting I shut down. I can later manage encrypted pass or login from DB with that user type. Bu I not need actually write any of it in web.confog

Comment: If you want the login to be disassociated with the login page.. get rid of the Forms Authentication part of the web page and create your own user name / password type of Authentication .. have it sit on top of LDAP or AD for example.. do you guys use SSO (That's Single Sign-On

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want membership:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx